# How do g++ and gcc differ on macOS if g++ is just an alias file?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I can compile C++ files by using both `g++` and `gcc`. However from my understanding when using `gcc` I need to pass the `-libgc+` option to automatically link against the C++ std library so that I don't get errors.

`g++` on the other hand automatically links against the std C++ library.

Doing `which g++` in the terminal leads to `/usr/bin` from where I can see that `/usr/bin/g++` is just an alias file pointing to `/usr/bin/gcc` which is an actual executable.

How is then `g++` able to automatically link against the std library if it's just a 3 byte alias file pointing to another executable?

Comment: One expression: `argv[0]`.